# The keypad and the note

Tags: cipher, story

You awake, in a room, with nothing. No item. Zero. Zilch. Nada.
Besides the decaying stone brick walls, there are only three things in the room:

- A **door**
- A **note**
- A **keypad**

You decide to look at all of them.

**Note:** There is no order to look at the objects. It doesn't necessarily matter.

---

You look at the **door**.

It seems to be rusted and made out of steel. You can clearly make out the thin line separating the two heavy chunks of metal blocking you from your escape. There is no way out, except for the keypad. In the corner of the door, you can see some writing, etched out: "Vmtkb2JHTnRWV2RoV0UxblltMDRaMXBZVG1wWldFSnNUR2xDVldSWVNuVkpSMHBvV1RKeloySnRPVE5NWjI4OUNnPT0K IS THREE"

Opening it manually seems to be an **UNDECIPHERABLE** task.

---

You look at the **keypad**.

Just your average keypad. It has the digits 0-9, an "ENTER" button, and a "CLEAR" button. It also seems to be connected to an alarm. Who knows what will happen if it rings?

The display seems to want 4 digits.

---

You look at the **note**.
The person who wrote it seemed to have made some letters darker, some letters crossed out, and some letters swayed.
**Begin note**

It's *ub*iqui*t*ous, and <s>b</s>y it, I mean yo<s>u</s>r <s>l</s>ife.
Your <s>l</s>if<s>e</s>. <s>T</s>hat's what I mean. I mean, I also love *c*ats. And I hate *x*enophobes. *X*enophobia as a whole is just so unnatural to me. Hopefully someone *f*ixes it. (And I don't mean that in a *h*ateful way.)

**Q**uestion: Are cats **b**ig? **B**ig? Well, I'll say no, t**h**ey are not.
But on a related note, my **g**reat grandma (related to the ancient **Ba**b**yl**onians) **q**uizz**e**d me on my **v**irtue. **I** couldn't ca**re** less.  Not even on a **q**uest. But, before my gradma died, she said one final thing to me:

**NEXARFFUNGRPNAGUNGYBIRQBQEVIRPNAABGBAYLYVTUGPNAUNGRGUNGQNEXARFFPNAABGBHGNEXARFFUNGRPNAGUNGYBIRQBQEVIRPNAABGBAYLYVTUGPNAUNGRGUNGQNEXARFFPNAABGBHG**

**End note**

---

You have to get out.
**But it seems impossible.**

***Unless...***

Comment: To save others the trouble, in the note: bold = `QbBhgBaylqevIreq`, italics = `ubtcxXfh`, strike = `bulleT`

Answer (score 4):

The encrypted `Vmtkb2JHTnRWV2RoV0UxblltMDRaMXBZVG1wWldFSnNUR2xDVldSWVNuVkpSMHBvV1RKeloySnRPVE5NWjI4OUNnPT0K IS THREE"` means

> There is no escape. Turn back now.

(I had to Base64 decode 3 times)

bold = `QbBhgBaylqevIreq` means `DoOutOnlydriVerd` rot13

italics = `ubtcxXfh` means `).` base64

strike = `bullet` plain text

The note means `NEXARFFUNGRPNAGUNGYBIRQBQEVIRPNAABGBAYLYVTUGPNAUNGRGUNGQNEXARFFPNAABGBHGNEXARFFUNGRPNAGUNGYBIRQBQEVIRPNAABGBAYLYVTUGPNAUNGRGUNGQNEXARFFPNAABGBHG`

> ARKNESSHATECANTHATLOVEDODRIVECANNOTONLYLIGHTCANHATETHATDARKNESSCANNOTOUTARKNESSHATECANTHATLOVEDODRIVECANNOTONLYLIGHTCANHATETHATDARKNESSCANNOTOUT rot13

means:

> Darkness cannot drive out darkness; only light can do that. Hate cannot drive out hate; only love can do that.

$\Rightarrow So$ $what?$ $I've$ $decrypted$ $some$ $part.$ $Now$ $it's$ $your$ $job.$

Comment: Your last block of text bears a strong resemblance to [a quote by Martin Luther King Jr.](http://www.values.com/inspirational-quotes/7171-darkness-cannot-drive-out-darkness-only-light).

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Would you mind editing in a bit more explanation. I can see some rot13, but I'm not quite understanding what decryption methods you've applied to get these results...

Comment: Now look @ it again

Answer (score 1):

> 5683  as LOVE on keypad following on from Learn How's work

Comment: Could you please explain why you think this is the answer? I'm not following..

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, George! This answer is currently in the low-quality queue because, as OnlyF noted, it lacks explanation (although I do think it might be correct). Please edit in an explanation, I'd hate for this to be deleted if it *is* correct.

Comment: This is correct, but could you tell me how you got to this answer?